# space in path using java

Tags: java

Hi, I have a big problem. I'm making a java program and I have to call an exe file in a folder that have whitespace. This program also has 2 arguments that always have whitspace in the path.
Example:

C:\Users\Program File\convert image\convert.exe C:\users\image exe\image.jpeg C:\Users\out put\out.bmp

I have to do this in Windows but i want generalize it for every OS.
 
My code is:

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();<br/>
String path_current = System.getProperty("user.dir");<br/>
String [] uno = new String[]{"cmd","/c",path_current+"\\\convert\\\convert.exe",path_current+"\\\f.jpeg", path_current+"\\\fr.bmp"};<br/>
Process proc2 = run.exec(uno);<br/>
proc2.waitFor();<br/>
```

This does not work. I tried removing the String array and inserting a simple String with "\"" before and after the path but that didn't work. How do I resolve this?

Comment: i'm sorry for that. Was not my intention to be informal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to use :
http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#separatorsToSystem(java.lang.String)

see also this answer :

[Is there a Java utility which will convert a String path to use the correct File separator char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697303/is-there-a-java-utility-which-will-convert-a-string-path-to-use-the-correct-file)

Answer (score 1):

Remove "cmd" and "/c", and use a single forward slash instead of your triple backslaches.