# Java Paths in Windows for Linux environment

Tags: java, linux, windows, filepath

I'm developing in Windows and somewhere in the flow I have to access sftp (Linux) server.
I do some logic to prepare filenames I have to copy from the sftp server and I need to generate the full path, therefore I write this line in my code:

```
Paths.get(configuration.getSftpServerConfiguration().getRemotePath(), filename).toString();
```

Because I’m running on Windows the paths generated with Windows slash, for example `\public\directory\filename.csv`

Can I define Paths to work with Linux separator? (I know I can concatenate ‘/’ by myself but looks for me like a bad practice..)

Comment: `Paths.get()` creates a path relative to your default filesystem. A `Path` is a pointer to a local filesystem. If you do not mount the sftp server as a local filesystem, you shouldn't access it using `Path`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thank you, does there is another java package I can use or I have to do it by myself?

Comment: I would check in the sftp library that you use whether it has a "separator" property or a path concatenation facility.

Comment: If you want to use `Path` then consider looking for a `FileSystemProvider` implementation for SFTP. Then you can interact with the remote server like it was just another file system. You'd have to use the implementation's `FileSystem` to create the paths, of course. Otherwise check your current library for the necessary functionality, as suggest by RealSkeptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this post: [Is there a Java utility which will convert a String path to use the correct File separator char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697303/is-there-a-java-utility-which-will-convert-a-string-path-to-use-the-correct-file)

Basically `FilenameUtils.separatorsToSystem(String path)`, of `Apache Commons`, will help achieve what you are trying to do.

If you do not want to import the entire dependency this is what the method does:

```
String separatorsToSystem(String res) {
    if (res==null) return null;
    if (File.separatorChar=='\\') {
        // From Windows to Linux/Mac
        return res.replace('/', File.separatorChar);
    } else {
        // From Linux/Mac to Windows
        return res.replace('\\', File.separatorChar);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
As @Slaw said, this solution is still Platform-dependent. You could modify the method to take an extra parameter, and decide if you want the output string in "Unix" or "Windows", something like this:

```
String changeFileSeparators(String res, boolean toUnix) {
    if (res==null) return null;
    if (toUnix) {
        // From Windows to Linux/Mac
        return res.replace('\\', '/');
    } else {
        // From Linux/Mac to Windows
        return res.replace('/', '\\');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! so I understand that there is no direct solution.. btw, nice trick :)

Comment: @AsfK This implementation is still platform-dependent, just like `Paths#get(String,String...)`. In other words, it uses the separator used by the host operating system.

Comment: @Slaw, Thanks I notice it, but it still nice trick, in my case I just replace \\ with / .. Now I read your commnet, I'll look in the sftp impl.